# Handle one to many relationship while keeping the many table updated as new items are added to the one table

Tags: database, one-to-many

I'm looking for best practices to set up a database to do the following:

The following example is not exactly what I'm programming, but I think it is analogous enough to get a relevant answer. I am trying to keep the example tables basic, but with just enough info for clarity.

If I were writing software for grocery stores, and I wanted each store to be able to customize their own items from a master list, I believe I would create the following tables:

**Master_list**

| id | year | item | item_description | sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023 | Apple | Delicious apple | 1111 |
| 2 | 2023 | Orange | Really orange orange | 2222 |
| 3 | 2023 | Banana | Organic banana | 3333 |

**Items**

| id | master*list*_id | store_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1.99 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2.05 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2.95 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 1.45 |

Each store could use an item from the master list and create their own price.

**Where I'm Stuck**

Let's say that every year the entire master list had to be copied because there was a new sku each year. In many cases, even though the sku changes, the actual product does not change at all (I know this isn't totally realistic here, but this is how it works in my project). So the master list might look something like this:

**Master_list**

| id | year | item | item_description | sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023 | Apple | Delicious apple | 1111 |
| 2 | 2023 | Orange | Really orange orange | 2222 |
| 3 | 2023 | Banana | Organic banana | 3333 |
| 4 | 2024 | Apple | Delicious apple | 4444 |
| 5 | 2024 | Orange | Really orange orange | 5555 |
| 6 | 2024 | Banana | Organic banana | 6666 |

Some stores can choose to stay on the 2023 master list, but others are required to move forward to the 2024 master list. What is the best way to move the stores items to the new year without them having to redo the price?

**Option**

1. One option I see is to create a new table that maps the master list items from the old to the new id.

   | old_id | new_id |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 4 |
   | 2 | 5 |

   ```
   Then I would use this table to update the Items table masterlist*id with the new*\_id.
   ```

This can work, but is there a better way to do this?